# App with no output when using PhoneGap Build

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I'm using PhoneGap Build to build the example app provided with PageSlider.js. After I upload the files in [this Git Repository](https://github.com/ccoenraets/PageSlider) to the PhoneGap build, I get the following message:

```
Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

But after deploying the app to my Windows Phone for testing the app is empty and nothing shows up in the screen.

I have tried the library and some of the provided code in this example for another test project. The other project has the same problem. I also have tried removing the cordova.js file and using the newest version.

Any ideas on what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what is the problem.

If the doctype line is not included in the html file Phonegap and Cordova will not execute the JavaScript files.

The following line should be included in all HTML files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```